# Напишите функцию, фильтрующую массив объектов по значению свойства JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты

Я учусь JS. Короче в одном из скаченных курсов есть задания. И вот там такое задание:

**Цель задания**
Попрактиковаться в использовании сложных структур данных (массив объектов) и работе со свойствами.
**Задание**
Напишите функцию, фильтрующую массив объектов по значению свойства. Массив, название свойства и нужное значение должны передаваться в качестве аргументов. Пример использования:

```
let objects = [
{ name: 'Василий', surname: 'Васильев' },
{ name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов' },
{ name: 'Пётр', surname: 'Петров' }
]

// fn - функция, которую нужно написать (хорошее название тоже нужно придумать)
let result = fn(objects, 'name', 'Иван');
```

/*
Результат выполнения должен быть:

```
[
{ name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов' }
]
```

*/
В конце файла с кодом домашнего задания напишите конструкцию export default {название функции}, чтобы была возможность автоматической проверки получившейся функции.

**Рекомендации к выполнению**
Не забывайте о том, что массивы и объекты передаются по ссылке. Поэтому для формирования массива-результата нужно создать новый отдельный массив, а не изменять старый, который пришёл в качестве параметра.

```
let objects = [
  { name: 'Василий', 
    surname: 'Васильев' },
  { name: 'Иван', 
    surname: 'Иванов' },
  { name: 'Пётр', 
    surname: 'Петров' }
  ]

  function filterObjValues(objects, key, value) {    //функция с 3мя атрибутами
    for (i=1; i <= objects.length; ++i) {             //цикл от 1 до 3 (так как длина массива обжектс 3)
      let obj = Object.values(objects[i]);            //переменная в которую кладу значения обжекста name Виселек surname Висилеков name Иван name Иванов и тд
      let objKeys = Object.keys(obj);                 // Переменная в которую кладу  только названия значений из прошлой переменной. name, surname
      let [keys1, keys2] = objKeys;                   //деструктаризирую (вот это слово).  теперь name находится в keys1 а surname в keys2
      let [name, surname] = obj;                       //деструктаризирую. теперь Василек находится в name,  а Васильков в surname.
       if (key === keys1 && value === name) {                  // условие если атрибут 'name' равен keys1 и 'Иван' равен name, То выполнить следующую строчку
         let result = `${keys1}:${name} ${keys2}:${surname}`;  //переменная = name:Иван surname:Иванов.
         console.log(result);                                  //выводим это в консоль.
       }
       }
      }

filterObjValues(objects, 'name', 'Иван');                  //запускаем функцию
```

Если можно подскажите куда я не правильно завернул? ничего не работает =)
Пока прошел (функции, циклы, деструктаризацию, условия, массивы и объекты), поэтому задание рассчитано максимум на это. Сердешко вам <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы переусложнили и кое-где свернули не туда) Вот возможный вариант с комментариями:

```js
let objects = [
  { name: 'Василий',
    surname: 'Васильев' },
  { name: 'Иван',
    surname: 'Иванов' },
  { name: 'Пётр',
    surname: 'Петров' }
];

function filterObjValues(objects, key, value) {
  // Нам нужно вернуть новый массив, так что создадим его.
  const result = [];

  // Индексы начинаются с 0. Переменную счётчика лучше объявлять с let.
  // Длина всегда больше последнего индекса, так что он должен быть меньше длины.
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    // получаем объект по индексу
    const obj = objects[i];

    // Если значение по key совпадает с value, добавляем объект в массив.
    if (obj[key] === value) result.push(obj);
  }

  // Из функции лучше возвращать значение, а выводить его уже вне функции.
  // Особенно если где-то будет проверятся работа функции и её результат.
  return result;
}

const filteredArray = filterObjValues(objects, 'name', 'Иван'); // Получаем значение.

console.log(filteredArray); // Выводим результат.
```

Так же я вам советую, когда что-то идёт не так, добавлять `console.log()` для каждой вашей переменной, чтобы проверять, всегда ли вы получаете то, что имеете в виду. Например, тут вы получаете не то, что хотите:

```js
let obj = Object.values(objects[i]); 
console.log(obj);
let objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(objKeys);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все строки вроде понятны, сейчас буду тестировать, нужно понять почему не туда свернул.  Отвечайте пожалуйста на все мои темы, хороший развернутый ответ с комментариями <3

Comment: Спасибо) Если буду знать ответ и будет время, то попытаюсь)

Answer (score 0):

```
let objects = [
  { name: 'Василий', surname: 'Васильев' },
  { name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов' },
  { name: 'Пётр', surname: 'Петров' }
]

function filter(objects, key, value) {
  let result = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    if(Object.keys(objects[i]).includes(key) == true && 
Object.values(objects[i]).includes(value) == true) {
      result.push(objects[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

filter(objects);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let arries = [
  { name: 'Василий', surname: 'Васильев' },
  { name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов' },
  { name: 'Пётр', surname: 'Петров' }
]

function filter(objects, key, value) {
  let newObjects = [];
  for (let object of objects) {
    if (object[key] === value) {
      newObjects.push(object);
      console.log(newObjects);
    }
  }
  return newObjects;
}

filter(arries, 'surname', 'Васильев');
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```js
const usersList = [{
    name: 'Петр',
    surname: 'Сидоров'
  },
  {
    name: 'Иван',
    surname: 'Петров'
  },
  {
    name: 'Илья',
    surname: 'Яблокин'
  },
  {
    name: 'Никита',
    surname: 'Иванов'
  },
  {
    name: 'Альберт',
    surname: 'Ильин'
  },
  {
    name: 'Иосиф',
    surname: 'Сталин'
  },
  {
    name: 'Владимир',
    surname: 'Ленин'
  },
  {
    name: 'Александр',
    surname: 'Пушкин'
  },
  {
    name: 'Иван',
    surname: 'Николаев'
  },
  {
    name: 'Марина',
    surname: 'Серьгина'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ирина',
    surname: 'Круг'
  },
  {
    name: 'Анна',
    surname: 'Кошкина'
  }
]

const dataFilter = (arrayChecked, elementProperty, desiredValue) => {
  const userSerch = arrayChecked.filter(item => item[elementProperty] === desiredValue)
  return userSerch
}

console.log(dataFilter(usersList, 'name', 'Иван'))
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]